# How do I repeat functionality to display links in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have an MVC view that I need to update.  The current code looks like this:

View -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestView";

}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h4>Current Report 1</h4>
        @if (@ViewBag.DocID != null)
        {
            <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DownloadFile('@ViewBag.DocID');" title="@ViewBag.DocName">@ViewBag.DocName</a> - <small>@ViewBag.UploadDateTime</small></p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>There is not a current Report in the system at this time.</p>
        }


    </div>
</div>
```

Controller -

```
    public ActionResult TestView()
    {
        Report report = new Report();
        SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria();

        sc.User = SessionData.User;
        sc.DocType = 1;
        report = DAL.GetReportWithTypeAndUser(sc);

        if(report != null)
        {
            ViewBag.DocID = report.DocID;
            ViewBag.DocName = report.DocName;
            ViewBag.UploadDateTime = report.UploadDateTime;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

This code works great the way it is.  But I need to repeat this for several more report types.  In my controller, I currently send a DocType = 1, but I would need to send 2, 3, 4, etc. and get several different types back and list them the same way as I currently do in my view.

I am having difficulties coming up with the best way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `ViewBag`. Use ViewModels instead.

ViewModel:

```
public class ReportsViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Report> Reports;
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Report
{
    public int DocID { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult TestView()
{
    // get your reports with different types
    var reports = GetYourReports();

    var vm = new ReportsViewModel
    {
         Reports = reports
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

View:

```
@model ReportsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestView";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @if (Model.Reports.Length > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var report in Models.Reports)
            {                     
                <p><a href="javascript:void(0); "onclick="DownloadFile('@report.DocID');" title="@report.DocName">@report.DocName</a> - <small>@report.UploadDateTime</small></p>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>There is not a current Report in the system at this time.</p>
        }
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a View Model and bind your view to that?

```
public class Report
{
    public int DocType {get; set;}
    public int DocId {get; set;}
    public string DocName {get; set;}
    // Other properties
}
```

Then you can bind your view to this model by adding `@model Report` at the top of the view, and access the properties by doing `@Model.DocType` etc. in the view. You can even write more complex logic in the view, customizing it based on the `DocType`.

In the controller you can create an instance of the `Report` class, and assign appropriate values to its properties, and pass this object to the `View` when you instantiate it.